# How do I hide the "Post to Facebook" option from the fb:comment method box?

Tags: facebook

I used the fb:comment method on my wordpress to allow users to interact using their facebook. but I don't want their comments to appear on their facebook, so I want to remove the "Post to Facebook" option from the comment box. how do I go about doing that? 
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

There doesn't appear to be any option to turn that off.  I think it's a great idea, you should log it as a wishlist item at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.  Post the bug report # here so others who stumble upon this question will know that it's been logged.